# Pre authentication trigger not being triggered for InitiateAuth function using Refresh Token from AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

When I am trying to run InitiateAuth function from AWS CLI as below

```
aws cognito-idp initiate-auth --auth-flow REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH --client-id <ClientId> --auth-parameters REFRESH_TOKEN=<refresh_token>,SECRET_HASH=<secret_hash>
```

I was expecting all the triggers mentioned in the [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html) to be hit , which includes PreAuthentication trigger, but the only trigger being hit is PreTokenGeneration Trigger. I have placed a dummyFunc lambda to be triggered by both the triggers, but it is only being triggered through PreTokenGeneration Trigger.

Comment: I think I'm missing the question here ;) But what you stated is nothing unusual. It's actually documented: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-authentication.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html

Comment: @AleksanderWons It says in the documentation for InitiateAuth
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html

""  When you use the InitiateAuth API action, Amazon Cognito invokes the AWS Lambda functions that are specified for various triggers. The ClientMetadata value is passed as input to the functions for only the following triggers:

Pre signup
Pre authentication
User migration
""
So I was expecting PreAuthentication Token to be hit, but on executing the aws initiateAuth command using refresh token, the trigger does not get hit

Comment: AWS can be sometimes misleading, but this works as expected. That's all.

Comment: @95_96 have you find any solution on that? I am facing the same problem, I don't see any way to pass the Client Metadata on the Refresh Token call.